# java programming, how to make doubly linked list in doubly linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

student.txt file consists of student's name, class_number(=ban), number.
for example

```
jack 4 3
mike 1 4
key 3 5 
peak 1 3
....
```

I want to know how to make class_number to doubly linked list(like a 1-2-3-4-5) (ban is equal to class_number). And each class_number is connected to student doubly linked list(ordered by their number)
Finally it prints out like  number name (<1class> 4 mike)

[image]

Thanks for reading

```
package nov25;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Ban {
    private int ban;
    private LinkedList<Student> list;

}
class Student {
    private int no;
    private String name;

}
public class P1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("student.txt");
        Scanner scin;
        if (file.exists()) {
           try {
             scin = new Scanner(file);
             while (scin.hasNext()) {
                 String name = scin.next();
                 int ban = scin.nextInt();
                 int no = scin.nextInt();
             }
             scin.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
        else {
           System.out.println("score.txt not exist!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use `java.util.LinkedList`, or do you have to create your own new implementation of doubly-linked list?

Comment: A fundamental path for solving programming problems is to break a big problem into small ones. You just need to define a class that can hold data and a reference to the first and last elements and you are good to go.

Comment: Your course notes, or the textbooks that go with your course, are going to explain this better than a SO answer can.